# where should i save accesstoken in mvc other than session

Tags: model-view-controller

As we all know one big advantage of MVC is stateless.

However if not using session, where should I save my accesstoken from facebook.
since i want user to be able to post feed to their wall, which requires accesstoken for authentication.

Is there any best practice that i can follow?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up save fb accessToken in my database by requiring user facebook extended permission: [offline_access](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)

I dont know how to delete the question, so I put my solution up here.

Answer (score 0):

See the StoreFacebookAuthToken method in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates.aspx) site.

I changed the code a bit and summarizing looked like this:

1. Add Identity Claim Facebook:access_token on **OnAuthenticated** event
2. Create a method to store the claim in **database**
3. Call the created method from **ExternalLoginCallback**, **LinkLoginCallBack** and **ExternalLoginConfirmation** Actions

See the code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8VFIf6p6-l8SjEyYnlKQ0tLNEk/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Sorry, I am newbie to Stackoverflow.. I tried to edit my answer uploading images with example, but 2 reputation points are needed yet :(

Comment: when you need to upload a picture just put a link to it, someone else can edit it to show here, but by now you can elaborate better with text